# Batch File Range

Tags: windows, batch-file

Thanks in advanced for your help!  I have a batch file question for you guys.  So we keep up with one of our client's backups.  They're located over 200 miles away from us.  We bring their backups over via remote desktop.  We've found that using the copy function via the command prompt is MUCH faster than any other method of copy/paste. The person who is in charge of bringing them over often forgets to do so.  I've only just started using batches, but I created a small batch program that will ask the user which file to bring over so he doesn't have to "copy n:\backups\blah \tsclient\h\backups\blah" which can be quite error prone.  The following is the batch file:

```
@echo off
title Copy Zipbacks

:loopagain
set /p date=Enter the date that needs to be copied over (yyyymmdd format):
copy h:\zipbackups\daily%date%.zipx \\tsclient\h\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups

set /p again=Copy Another Daily Zip file? (Y/N):

IF "%again%"=="Y" GOTO loopAgain
IF "%again%"=="N" GOTO goAway

:goAway
exit
```

This is good if there are only a handful of backups to be brought over.  My question is this; Is there a way to bring over a range of backups?  The file is setup as follows:

```
dailyYYYYMMDD.zipx
i.e. daily20140917.zipx
```

I have no problem asking for the date range, but getting the .bat to loop through the folder and getting only those that meet the criteria is where I'm running into the issue.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `for` to enumerate files:

```
@echo off
title Copy Zipbacks

:loopagain
set /p start_date=Enter start date that needs to be copied over (yyyymmdd format):
set /p end_date=Enter end date (yyyymmdd format) or nothing to match only start date:
if not defined end_date set end_date=%start_date%
for %%f in (h:\zipbackups\daily*.zipx) do if "%%~nf" geq "daily%start_date%" if "%%~nf" leq "daily%end_date%" copy %%f \\tsclient\h\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups

set /p again=Copy Another Daily Zip file? (Y/N):

IF "%again%"=="Y" GOTO loopAgain
IF "%again%"=="N" GOTO goAway

:goAway
exit
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine. Perhaps it would be nicer to use `choice /c YN /m "Copy Another Daily Zip file?"` instead of `set /p`. The checks then turn into `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==2 GOTO goAway` `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 GOTO loopAgain`. In general, putting an exit into a script becomes problematic when the script starts getting called from other places, best not to do it.

Comment: @LS_dev, thanks for your input!  I really appreciate your help.  So just add a couple of `if statements`?  That's super easy!  I have one question for you though.  What does `"%%~nf"` do?

Comment: @Jim, I tried my best to get the `choice` to work when I first started writing the original script and it would always just repeat the first `ERRORLEVEL` no matter if I put Y or N.  I'll give it another shot because I'm not going to let it beat me that easy

Comment: @Jim I just added required functionality, not changed existing code.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey `%%~nf`returns just name part from path. Check `for /?`.

Comment: @LS_dev, yours works almost perfectly!  The only thing I changed was to set the `end_date` to spaces before asking for a reply. If you bring over a range of dates then try to bring over a single date and not fill in the `end_date`, it retains the last date that was input for the `end_date` and you could potentially be in a heap of a mess.  Anyway, thank you again for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I came across a trick with xcopy that lets you generate a sequence of valid dates. The following script will generate the sequence and then copy each of the files.

```
@echo off

::set /p date=Enter the start date that needs to be copied over (yyyymmdd format):
::set /p end=Enter the end date that needs to be copied over (yyyymmdd format):
set /a date=20010218
set /a end=20010302

set /a y=%date:~0,4%
set /a m=%date:~4,2%
set /a d=%date:~6,2%
echo INPUT = %y% %m% %d%

:getnextvaliddate
   set /a d+=1

   if %d% gtr 31 (
      set d=1
      set /a m+=1

      if %m% gtr 12 (
         set m=1
         set /a y+=1
      )
   )

echo %y% %m% %d%

xcopy /d:%m%-%d%-%y% /h /l "%~f0" "%~f0\" >nul 2>&1 || goto getnextvaliddate

call :prettydate

if %y% equ %end:~0,4% (
  if %m% equ %end:~4,2% (
    if %d% equ %end:~6,2% (
      goto :EOF
    )
  )
)

goto :getnextvaliddate

:prettydate
if %d% lss 10 (
  set dd=0%d%
) else (
  set dd=%d%
)
if %m% lss 10 (
  set mm=0%m%
) else (
  set mm=%m%
)
echo copy h:\zipbackups\daily%y%%mm%%dd%.zipx \\tsclient\h\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups
goto :EOF
```

Output on my machine:

```
INPUT = 2001 2 26
2001 2 27
copy h:\zipbackups\daily20010227.zipx \\tsclient\h\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups
2001 2 28
copy h:\zipbackups\daily20010228.zipx \\tsclient\h\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups
2001 2 29
2001 2 30
2001 2 31
2001 3 1
copy h:\zipbackups\daily20010301.zipx \\tsclient\h\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups
2001 3 2
copy h:\zipbackups\daily20010302.zipx \\tsclient\h\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups
```