# MID function for Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I'm back with a batch file question.  I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899594/batch-file-range) question about getting ranges in a batch file so we can more easily bring over backups.  Once the file has been copied to our system, we unzip the file so we have a "running backup" of our client's data. What I'm trying to accomplish now is to move the file that was just been unzipped from its current directory to an archive directory. So far I have the following:

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%i IN (H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\ZipBackupsList.txt) DO (
c:\wzzip\wzunzip -o -d H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%i h:\benton_off_site_backup\
move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%i H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped
)
exit
```

This is fine, but the `AlreadyUnzipped` folder contains sub-folders labeled by the year.  The year folders have sub-folders labeled by month.

```
i.e. H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\2014\1.January
     H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\2014\2.February
     ...
```

These folders contain everything that has been unzipped.  What I would like to happen is once the unzipping process has been completed, I would like the file to be moved to it's corresponding archive folder. An example would be:

```
daily20140105.zipx
```

needs to go to

```
H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\2014\1.January
```

I've done some research online and found [this](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) website, but have been unable to get anything to happen.  I've been doing the MID equivalent.  If I need to further explain myself, then I will gladly do so.  Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Much thanks to @David Ruhmann for all his help!  His got me to this point

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "count=0"
for %%A in (January February March April May June July August September October November December) do set /a "count+=1" & set "month[!count!]=%%A"

FOR /F %%i IN (H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\ZipBackupsList.txt) DO (
c:\wzzip\wzunzip -o -d H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%i h:\benton_off_site_backup\

set "filename=%%~ni"
set "mm=!filename:~-4,2!"
if "!filename:~-4,1!"=="0" set "mm=!filename:~-3,1!"
call move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%~i H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!filename:~-8,4!\!mm!.%%month[!mm!]%%\%%i
```

When I debug it, the following is echoed it out.

```
move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\daily20140920.zipx
H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\2014\9.September\daily20140920.zipx
```

The paths are correct, but it doesn't do anything!  It only extracts the file, then says the system can't find the path and moves to the next file to be extracted.  GRRRR!

FINISHED:

I'm so very grateful to @DavidRuhmann and @Magoo.  Without their help and keen insight, I would be stuck spinning my wheels in vein pursuit of an answer.  I've used both of their input for my final program which is what follows:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "count=0"
for %%A in (January February March April May June July August September October November December) do set /a "count+=1" & set "month[!count!]=%%A"

FOR /F %%i IN (H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\ZipBackupsList.txt) DO (
 c:\wzzip\wzunzip -o -d H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%i h:\benton_off_site_backup\

 set "filename=%%~ni"
 set "mm=!filename:~-4,2!"
 if "!filename:~-4,1!"=="0" set "mm=!filename:~-3,1!"
 CALL SET "monthdir=!filename:~-8,4!\!mm!.%%month[!mm!]%%"
 MD H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!monthdir! 2>NUL
 call move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%~i H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!monthdir!\%%i

)
endlocal
exit
```

If you're still reading this, go give these guys some love by up-voting their contributions.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do what you requested.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "count=0"
for %%A in (January February March April May June July August September October November December) do set /a "count+=1" & set "month[!count!]=%%A"

FOR /F %%i IN (H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\ZipBackupsList.txt) DO (
c:\wzzip\wzunzip -o -d H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%i h:\benton_off_site_backup\

set "filename=%%~ni"
set "mm=!filename:~-4,2!"
if "!filename:~-4,1!"=="0" set "mm=!filename:~-3,1!"
call move "H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%~i" "H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!filename:~-8,4!\!mm!.%%month[!mm!]%%\%%~i"

)
endlocal
exit
```

Comment: so I ran this and I'm not entirely sure what it did.  I'll do my best to explain what it did. It did unzip the files, but after that the file wasn't moved to the corresponding archive folder. When the batch was finished running a new file called AlreadyUnzipped had been created in the same directory.    My best guess is that maybe the zip file was moved to the AlreadyUnzipped file.  I appreciate your input.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Change the `@echo off` to `@echo on` and add `echo` in between the `call move` commands (`call echo move`) and change the `exit` to `pause` to debug the script.  Also, do the AlreadyUnzipped and sub folders exist or do they need to be created?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!  I will definitely do some debugging.  The AlreadyUnzipped subfolders already exist.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Glad to try and help and sorry that I do not know the resolution off the top of my head, but if you can post the result of the `echo`, I might be able to get a better idea about the point of failure.  It might be an oversight in my changes or some unhandled scenario that I missed from writing my answer just from my head. **`:)`**

Comment: set "filename=daily20140916"
 set "mm=!filename~-4,2!"
 if "!filename~-4,1!" == "0" set "mm=!filename~-3,1!"
 call echo move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\daily20140916.zipx H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!filename~-8,4!\!mm!.%month[!filename~-4,2!]%
I only copied what I thought would be relevant. I think there needs to be colons before the tildes.  I'm not positive though.

Comment: move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\daily20140916.zipx H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\2014\09.
It's missing the month name.  It only ends with the period

Comment: Yep the colons are needed. I will edit my answer when i get back to a computer. Must also have an issue with the month logic. Will also look at it again a bit later. Thanks for debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61770/discussion-between-michael-harvey-and-david-ruhmann).

Answer (score 1):

Solely addressing the error now encountered - and this is purely "air code" (theoretical and untested)

(noting also that the `for` has an unclosed parenthesis - probably a cut-and-paste glitch)

```dos
FOR /F %%i IN (H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\ZipBackupsList.txt) DO (
 c:\wzzip\wzunzip -o -d H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%i h:\benton_off_site_backup\

 set "filename=%%~ni"
 set "mm=!filename:~-4,2!"
 if "!filename:~-4,1!"=="0" set "mm=!filename:~-3,1!"
 SET "monthdir=!filename:~-8,4!\!mm!.%month[!mm!]%"
 echo(MD H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!monthdir!
 ECHO(move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%~i H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!monthdir!\%%i\
)
```

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

---

further thoughts:

Certainly, the expansion is faulty.

```
 CALL SET "monthdir=!filename:~-8,4!\!mm!.%%month[!mm!]%%"
```

should work. It does for me.

Meanwhile - the two `echo`ed lines:

The extra `MD` of an existing directory will do no harm. Call it a safety measure if you like; omit it if you like. As I documented, if you remove the `echo(` and append `2>nul` then the error message generated for an existing directory will be suppressed.

Finally, I believe that the cause of the 'can't find the file' message may be the terminal `\` in the `move` command - I was under the impression that the destination was a directory specification, not a file specification, so that terminal `\` should be omitted.

Revised batch segment:

```dos
FOR /F %%i IN (H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\ZipBackupsList.txt) DO (
 c:\wzzip\wzunzip -o -d H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%i h:\benton_off_site_backup\

 set "filename=%%~ni"
 set "mm=!filename:~-4,2!"
 if "!filename:~-4,1!"=="0" set "mm=!filename:~-3,1!"
 CALL SET "monthdir=!filename:~-8,4!\!mm!.%%month[!mm!]%%"
 echo(MD H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!monthdir!
 ECHO(move H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\%%~i H:\benton_off_site_backup\zipbackups\AlreadyUnzipped\!monthdir!\%%i
)
```

Comment: The folder structure has arleady been created.  Wouldn't the `MD` re-create the folder every time?  If not then I'm lost as to why it wouldn't. If it wouldn't then could you explain why it wouldn't?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  The `md` command will only create a new directory if the directory does not exist.  If the directory already exists then it will output the message `A subdirectory or file <item> already exists.`  Therefore, it does not hurt to call the `md` command as much as you want.

Comment: @Magoo I do not think the `monthdir` expansion will work correctly since the `%month[!mm!]%` will expand before the `!mm!`.  That is why I used the `call` and `%%` method. Also the end of the `move` command has an extra backslash after the destination filename `%%i`.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann, you're completely right.  I didn't know how to explain what was happening, but apparently you knew.  I kept getting `%9.month[9]%` and nothing I still got the `can't find the folder` when I removed the echos.